# Bootstrap is not working in react app and how to import bootstrap.js file in a component?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

Anyone have suggestions about how to overcome the problem of styling and  bootstrapjs and css files not working in react app and how to import bootstrapjs file in react component.

I have created a toggler navbar with bootstrap and using popover and bootstrap files not working

```
import React from 'react';
import SwiperDiv from './swiper';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SwiperDiv/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:1375 Warning: React does not recognize the `classNmae` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `classnmae` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: Please attach code for `swiper` file

Comment: visual studio code is not picking the css (bootstrap.min.css) from node modules

Comment: I gave the path correctly visual studio code sugeest the path 'bootstrap/dist/css' it whould not show the acual file bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I write it by myself but whould not working

Comment: no error occurs in console and style is also not applied.

Comment: what should I do now please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo on your DOM element

> classNmae

try className

Answer (score 0):

From your error message I'm guessing somewhere in your code (probably `./swiper`) you wrote `classNmae` instead of `className` and that's what is causing your issue.

Also, in the code you posted you're closing a div tag inside the return statement without its opening tag present, so it's definitely going to throw an error. You should probably do:

```
return (
  <div>
    <SwiperDiv/>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

add bootstrap's 
 link and scripts

inside root "public/index.html" directory if you've created react APP using create-react-app

Comment: I have done it. the following error ocuurrs in console

Comment: localhost/:1 Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://localhost:3000/src/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'MsZC0igy9jcwulUMrBEeC4p8pFcxxGDzjPy6s3lO5as='. The resource has been blocked.